# How to generate an independent copy of namespace in below code

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, namespaces, deep-copy

Why I cant generate a copy of rst in below code? I need to have a data structure like what you see below and then make independent copies with different values from it. guide me what is my mistake?

```
from copy import deepcopy

class rst:
    a=2
    b=4
    c=[]
    
m=deepcopy(rst)
print(id(m)==id(rst))
```

True

according @Sayse comments (in the below comments) I used dataclass but still I have same problem and instances or copies of rst still are not independent and have same id.

```
from copy import deepcopy
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class rst:
    a=2
    b=4
    c=[]
    
m=deepcopy(rst)
print(id(m)==id(rst))
```

Comment: Are you trying to make instances of `rst` or multiple copies of the class to replicate the same behaviour?

Comment: My main purpose is to have a main variable (rst) with specific sub variables(a,b,c) and I want to make a lot of copy or instances of it that each copy or instance have its own value and do not have any affect on the other other copies or instances

Comment: Isn't that describing exactly what instances of a class are? I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do here

Comment: Imagine that I have a car that have some properties like color, length, company.

Now I want to make different instances like:
        -black,3,volvo
        -blue,4,ferary
and ....

These are only data and I don't want to use __init__ (if it is possible)

Comment: If all you're trying to do is not write an init then perhaps you're after a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), I'm not sure what the issue is still

Comment: @Sayse I put your suggestion in the below code but still instances are same. do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks because of your comments (Specially @rv.kvetch and @Sayse). This is exactly what I needed and searching for.

```
from copy import deepcopy
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class rst:
    a=2
    b=4
    c=[]
    
m=deepcopy(rst())
n=deepcopy(rst())
print(id(m)==id(n))
m.a=2
n.a=3
m.a
```

False

2

Comment: Well, *of course* the id's are similar - in above, `a,b,c` are **class** or static variables, not dataclass *fields*.

Comment: also, you're not instanting the class anywhere. try it like `deepcopy(rst())` instead - note the paranthesis there to create a new obect of class.